# Accessing PHP page with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm not from USA/England, so please excuse my poor English.

I'm currently working on a secure web page. Main structure of page is:

- folder **WWW** (here are all .php files that can be directly accessed, .js and .css files)
- folder **includes** (here are all php classes I'm using: functions.php, database.php etc..This folder can't be directly
  accessed)

So in my .js file (in WWW folder) I'm using ajax to call file ajax.php (in includes folder). Problem is, that it shows error 404 (file not found).

My current code (custom.js - in WWW folder):

```
dataUrl = "column="+col+"&type="+typ+"&nacin="+m;
$.ajax({
        url:"../includes/panelTable.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:dataUrl,
        success:function(data){
            $("#placeForADMTable").html(data);
        }
 });
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Create a wrapper function in a public php script that calls whatever you need in ajax.php

Comment: 'I'm using ajax to call file ajax.php (in includes folder)' - No your not you are calling 'panelTable.php'. Is this the same **includes** folder that 'can't be directly accessed'?

Comment: I think George Lee is right here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code (it works OK on localhost). Looks like there is problem with accessing to folder includes. If you go [here](https://212.235.189.234/includes/test1.php), you'll see that it shows 404 error (that's because folder includes can't be directly accessed). I can include that file in my code, but looks like I can't call it with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> folder includes...This folder can't be directly accessed

So why are you surprised that you can't access a file inside that folder?

Keeping your include files outside the document root (or another method preventing access from a browser) is good practice. Hence the include file should stay where it is. Just add a PHP script within www which invokes the include file, e.g.

```
<?php
// www/indirectPanelTable.php

require "../includes/panelTable.php";
```

And amend your ajax to point at that:

```
dataUrl = "column="+col+"&type="+typ+"&nacin="+m;
$.ajax({
    url:"indirectPanelTable.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:dataUrl,
    success:function(data){
        $("#placeForADMTable").html(data);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `ajax url` like below:

```
$.ajax({
     url:"includes/panelTable.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:dataUrl,
     success:function(data){
        $("#placeForADMTable").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User a wrapper for it (normally `$(document).ready(...)`) as such:

```
$( document ).ready( function () //Make sure yur page is ready
{
    dataUrl = "column=" + $( "#col_selector" ).val() + "&type=" + $( "#typ_selector" ).val() + "&nacin=" + $("#m_selector").val();
    $.ajax( {
        url: "includes/panelTable.php", // Surely you want to be able to access this as you kinda need it?
        type: "POST",
        data: dataUrl,
        success: function ( data )
        {
            $( "#placeForADMTable" ).html( data );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Also, you could be missing the `col`, `typ` and `m`, therefore use the ID for the inputs/elements to get the value at this point.

Also as **SHAZ** said, amend you URL to not be an absolute path, but the path from root (it looks from the beginning by default).

Another solution would be to include the file you need from the include directory in another PHP script and access this with AJAX.